# Regex for extract numbers and extension of string

Tags: php, regex

I use code below for extract numbers and file name of strings with problem standardization

```
30183308__90_.jpeg
30193253-(100).jpg
30193253__100__.jpg 
30193253_ _100_ _.jpg
```

Use this function

```
public function refactorFileName($filename)
{
    $array = preg_split("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $filename);
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value == "") {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    $array              = array_values($array);
    $standardFilename   = $array[0].'.'.$array[2];
    $indexFile          = $array[1];

    return compact("indexFile","standardFilename");
}

$filename = '30193253_ _100_ _.jpg';
extract(refactorFileName($filename));
echo "New File name -> ".$standardFilename.PHP_EOL;
echo "Index for file -> ".$indexFile.PHP_EOL;
```

This show (correct):

```
New File name -> 30193253.jpg
Index for file -> 100
```

I think there're a better code for regex expresion.

EDIT: 
It's possible better code on preg_split or better code in general for this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? easier to read/understand, better performance, etc.?

Comment: So, this is working code and you're just asking how to improve it?

Comment: Yes. I think there a better way for make code. Especially in the regex used in preg_split. IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: 1) It will be easier if you put a quantifier in your pattern (to avoid the useless `foreach` after). *(Note that `preg_split` has also the option `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to avoid empty items.)*
2) sometimes too much verbosity kills the verbosity.

Your can rewrite it this way:

```
function refactorFileName($filename) {
    $p = preg_split('~[\W_]+~', $filename, 3);

    return [ 'indexFile' => $p[1], 'standardFilename' => "$p[0].$p[2]" ];
}
```

Or if you want to be more verbose:

```
function refactorFileName($filename) {
    list($name, $index, $ext) = preg_split('~[\W_]+~', $filename, 3);

    return [ 'indexFile' => $index, 'standardFilename' => "$name.$ext" ];
}
```

*(As an aside, when you already have a working code, ask your question on codereview instead of SO)*

Comment: Thanks. Tomorrow test this way.  Apreciate for tip PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY (I've forgotten)

Comment: Tested. Thank you for understanding my question, and make the effort to help.